# Нужно перезагрузить скрипт на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть блок добавления товара, где выбор категории фотографии работают через скрипт `(input.hidden)`. Соответственно, эмулируется нажатие и внос информации через JavaScript, и должна быть возможность копирования этого блока. Только после копирования скрипты на второй блок не работают (конечно при `$(document).ready` его же не было). Так сам вопрос: как заставить скрипты принять новые блоки и работать с ними?

P.S. Добавлял эти функции в функцию клона — появляется проблема двойного срабатывания скрипта для первого блока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться делегированной обработкой событий.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-new', function(){
  // любой клик по документу вызывает проверку
  // если текущий элемент соответствует селектору - обработчик выполняется
});
```

```js
var list = $('#list');

$(document).on('click', '.btn-new', function(){
  console.log($(this).index(), $(this).html());
});

function add() {
  list.append($('<button class="btn-new">New button</button>'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="add()">+Add</button>

<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, воспользовался данным способом, заработало.